# get the icons native android?

Tags: android

can anyone tell me where I get the icons native android?

Comment: "The icons"? What icons?

Comment: sorry apache we can't understand your question in this format. Try to reformulate the question to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: where can I download all the icons native android?

Comment: That didn't clear up anything.

Answer (score 14):

I think what you are asking for is the icons that are used by the Android OS. If that's the case you can view them in the android.jar file that is installed with the SDK.

```
<sdk-install-path>/platforms/<any-platform>/android.jar
```

If you extract that jar and have a look at the res/drawable* folders you will see the icons used throughout the OS. You can also access them from within your code using:

`@android:drawable/<name of drawable>`

Comment: If you just want the image files for customization, this is by far the fastest way to grab them.

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear if you want to access the icons as files or through your application. If you want the actual icons you can grab them from the source code.

The source code for Android is available here at android.googlesource.com:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/

Specifically:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/

Many of the Android icons / resources are available by resource ID. The resource IDs for those are in the android.R class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Comment: If that answered your question, please mark it as so.  Thanks!

For future questions, remember the more details you give us, the better we can answer your question.  Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: android.git.kernel.org links are broken, domain doesn't seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[Material Icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) seems to be a good address for a standard Icon set for android these days.

Comment: @UdiOshi I modified the answer and point to the material design guidelines now

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.yay.se/resources/android-native-icons it contains all the standard icons converted to vector graphics.
[image]

Comment: Your link is broken. =(. Is there any alternative?

Comment: This answer is totally out of date.